# Trouble with finding characters in a string

Tags: c++, string, find, substr

I'm new to c++ though I have basic knowledge of Java, I'm trying to make a program that converts roman numeral input and then finds the equivalent arabic number and outputs it. However I am having an issue of finding the specific prefixes in the roman numerals I'm trying to use the str.find function and then using str.substr to test to see if the prefix exists and if so it gives the arabic value, and then will continue onto the next prefix. However my code seems to fail or print out "0". I am wondering if I am using the str functions wrong, or would there be a easier way to find prefixes in a string?

Here is my current code:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>



using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    string roman_digits [] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    string roman_tens [] = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    string roman_hundreds [] = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    string roman_thousands [] = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};
    string line, substr;

    int arabic = 0;


    // MCCCXXXVII

    cout << "Type in a Roman numeral: ";

    // Loops through inputted Roman Numerals.    
    while (cin >> line) {
        if (!cin.eof()) {
            int i = 0;

            // Loops through a Roman numeral and changes it to uppercase.
            while (line[i]) {
                char c;
                c = line[i];
                c = (toupper(c));
                line[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the thousands array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


                if (line.find("MMM") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("MMM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else if (line.find("MM") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("MM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else if (line.find("M") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("M");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }
                if (roman_thousands[i] == substr){
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 1000);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the hundreds array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("CM") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("DCCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DCCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4);
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                } else  if (line.find("DCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("DC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("D") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("D");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                } else  if (line.find("CD") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CD");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("CCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                }else  if (line.find("CC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("C") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("C");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }

                if (roman_hundreds[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 100);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the tens array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("XC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("LXXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LXXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4);
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                }else  if (line.find("LXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("LX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("L") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("L");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }else  if (line.find("XL") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XL");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("XXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);  
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                }else  if (line.find("XX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("X") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("X");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1); 
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }


                if (roman_tens[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 10);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the digits array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("IX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("IX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("VIII") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VIII");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4); 
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                } else  if (line.find("VII") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VII");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("VI") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VI");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("V") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("V");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                } else  if (line.find("IV") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("IV");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("III") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("III");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("II") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("II");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("I") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("I");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);                  
                }


                if (roman_digits[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + i;

                }
            }
            cout << "The Arabic equivalent of " << line << " is: " << arabic << endl;
            arabic = 0;
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid Roman numeral." << endl;
        }


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

EDIT: So I took the advice and it all seems to be working alright (Code has been edited), so thanks alot for that. ^^

However, since it is checking for "X" separately and deleting it my program is translating the input "IX" as 11 when it is actually 9. I know this has to do with the order that my program finds the prefixes in the strings, however I'm not sure on how to fix it, so any help on that would be great.

Thanks again

Comment: The check for `std::cin.eof()` doesn't really make much sense. Since you already check that the input was successful, it doesn't do much harm but it would prevent the last value if it isn't followed by a whitespace, e.g., a missing newline at the end of the file. Just remove it! BTW, `std::cin >> line` doesn't read a line but a word. If you really want to read a line use `std::getline(std::cin, line)` instead.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `std::map`.  You could use the Roman Numeral string as the key and the decimal value as the value in a [key, value] pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string::find` does not return a bool (as you see on the next line). If the string is not found, it returns a special constant `string::npos`. A value of 0 means the string was found at the beginning, not a failure.

Try this instead

```
string::size_type pos = line.find("MMM");
if (pos != string::npos)
{
    ...
}
```

Other comments

Here is a one-line way to convert a string to upper case. You will need to include `<algorithm>`

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
```

You could make your data arrays such as roman_digits `const string` to prevent modifying them by accident.

Try to declare variables as close as possible to their first use. `char c` only needs to be defined within your while loop, for example.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll take these things in mind in the future. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string::find()` function don't return a Boolean value but rather return the position of the found substring or `std::string::npos` if there is no such position. Thus, your tests probably should look like this:

```
if (line.find("MMM") != std::string::npos) { ... }
```

Of course, it doesn't really make much sense to try the same sequence of tests four times. You probably meant to the index `i` to select the appropriate string from the thousands array and have just one test. Of course, you would want to reverse the order of string or count down to be useful.

For the other checks you probably should use `find()` as well as there may be additional digits following.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is simpler, I did not implement error checking but it should not be hard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int fromRoman(string n)
{
    map<char, int> m;
    m['I'] = 1;
    m['V'] = 5;
    m['X'] = 10;
    m['L'] = 50;
    m['C'] = 100;
    m['D'] = 500;
    m['M'] = 1000;
    int tmp = 0;
    int res = 0;
    for (string::iterator i = n.begin(); i != n.end(); ++i)
    {
        int d = m[*i];
        if (d < tmp)
        {
            res += tmp;
            tmp = d;
        }
        else if (d > tmp)
        {
            if (tmp == 0)
                tmp = d;
            else
            {
                res += d - tmp;
                tmp = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (d == tmp)
        {
            res += tmp + d;
            tmp = 0;
        }
    }
    return res + tmp;
}

int main()
{
    const char *romanNumbers[] = {
        "IV", "VIII", "IX", "XXXI", "XLVI", "XCIX", "DLXXXIII", "DCCCLXXXVIII", 
        "MDCLXVIII", "MCMLXXXIX", "MMX", "MMXII", "MMMCMXCIX"
    };
    for (const char **r = romanNumbers; r != romanNumbers + sizeof(romanNumbers) / sizeof(*romanNumbers); ++r)
        cout << *r << " is " << fromRoman(*r) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
IV is 4
VIII is 8
IX is 9
XXXI is 31
XLVI is 46
XCIX is 99
DLXXXIII is 583
DCCCLXXXVIII is 888
MDCLXVIII is 1668
MCMLXXXIX is 1989
MMX is 2010
MMXII is 2012
MMMCMXCIX is 3999
```